# Calling a JavaScript function on a CKeditor dialog instead of a popup window

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I currently have a custom dialog within the link plugin that launches a popup with all the internal pages on my CMS for the user to pick and it inputs the url into the box

```
{type:'button',id:'browseInternal',label:i.browseWebsite,filebrowser:{action:'Browse',url:'/admin/pages/links'}}
```

However, I now use a popup modal window all over my system and would like the same modal style window to be used here. Any ideas on how I can implement it? I dont want to launch a popup window but instead the button needs to call this function

```
loadPopup( '/admin/pages/links', '', 'destination' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gathering my thoughts and a little more help from Google I eventially found the right page on the CKeditor docs [see here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.button.html)